# CSS class inheritance?

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of classes that end up like.

```
.img-small {
  color: #202124;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  max-width: 13px;
}

.img-med {
  color: #202124;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  max-width: 23px;
}
```

In this case the only difference being the width and very often these classes are used for exactly one image.

I'm tempted to use the width property but I know that's deprecated, so then I'm tempted to use a class that all it does is set the width (i.e. `class="img-base w-23"`), but is there really no better way so that I can override just one field? If possible I'd like to do something like.

```
.img-small {
  color: #202124;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  max-width: 13px;  
}

.img-med = img-small {
  max-width: 23px;
}
```

Is there something like this in vanilla CSS?

Comment: Why not `.img-small, .img-med {`…all properties except `max-width`…`} .img-small { max-width: 13px; } .img-med { max-width: 23px; }`?

Comment: Maybe another approach could be making a generic `.img` related item that contains the settings that would be common for all or most of your image related styles. Then, you could make specific `.img-small` (using your naming) type items with settings that are different. Later, when you want to use the CSS somewhere, just make sure to include both the common `.img` part as well as the specific `.img-small` part in your HTML or wherever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 2 classes per element. (side note: why are you setting your images to be only 13 pixels wide? that's very tiny)

```css
.img {
  color: #202124;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;  
}
.img-med {
  max-width: 23px;
}
.img-small {
  max-width: 13px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img img-med" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png"/>
<img class="img img-small" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png"/>
```

Comment: I figured that'd be the answer. These are logos at the bottom of emails so not meant to to look at for detail. I guess my fear of using two classes stems simply from what if-ism where I'm thinking about how most images will need to be tagged as both img-base and a size, rather than as just a size.